# difference between SERVICE - SERVICE_RESTARTING and IMPORTANT_FOREGROUND - RECEIVER process state

Tags: android

Can anyone help me understand the difference between 
SERVICE - SERVICE_RESTARTING and IMPORTANT_FOREGROUND - RECEIVER process state?

The documentation states:

> SERVICE - SERVICE_RESTARTING
>   Applications that are making themselves run in the background for their own reason. Most common problem apps have when they run in the background too much. %duration * pss is probably a good "badness" metric, although this set is so focused that just doing %duration is probably better to focus on the fact that we just don't want them running at all.
>   IMPORTANT_FOREGROUND - RECEIVER
>   Applications running in the background (not directly interacting with the user) for any reason. These all add memory load to the system. In this case the (%duration * pss) badness value is probably the best ordering of such processes, because many of these will be always running for good reason, and their pss size then is very important as part of their memory load.

I don't understand the difference between "the background for their own reason." and "in the background (not directly interacting with the user) for any reason".